# 信号処理について

Tags: matlab

信号処理の授業を取っているのですが
このような問題が出ました。

> Draw the block diagram for the difference equation below
>
> y[n] = x[n-1] + 0.5x[n-2] + y[n-1]

意味がわかりません
解答・解説をお願いいたします

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　この場合の block diagram の定義は先生から教わっていますか？　単に block diagram というだけだと色々なものがありますが、何でも良いのか、決まった書き方をするべきなのかが分からないな、と思いました。

Answer (score 0):

私の手元にペンタブがあったのでそれで描いてみます。もしかしたらz^(-2)じゃなくz^(-1)だけでかかないといけないかもしれないですし、0.5は三角形（アンプ）で描かないといけないかもしれません。テキストをご参照ください。
[image: 図１]